Identifying a Movie called "Espionage"
I'm trying to identify a movie that I saw on TV sometime in the 90's or early 2000's.  We had digital cable in the house so it could be either on one of the broadcast networks or on a premium channel like HBO.  And being on television, it could either be a TV movie or a theatrical film.  It's an American movie, and I think it was a fairly recent movie at the time.  I'm pretty sure the movie was titled "Espionage"; I remember that clearly because at the time I was too young to know what espionage meant.  Yet I can't seem to find any movie with that title on IMDB, so it's conceivable that I'm misremembering the title.
Plot Summary: It is about an old man who is an expert thief.  One night, a young woman working undercover for the police breaks into the man's house, claiming that she is a fellow thief and wants to learn the tricks of the trade from him.  He's immediately suspicious of her, assuming that she's a cop trying to spy on him and catch him in the act, but he grows to trust her and starts training her in the art of robbery.  I remember at one point they steal a valuable mask from a museum or something (she tries to give it to the people she's working for, but he replaces it with a fake before she can).  Anyway, his suspicions never entirely go away, and at one point I think he even threatens to kill her and she shouts something like "I promise I'm not a cop!"  I think the man and woman also have some romance/romantic tension.
Now at the end of the movie comes a shocking twist: it turns out the woman really is a thief!  And the expert thief was working for the cops the whole time, helping them in catching her!  The cops knew he was an expert thief, so they paid him to gain the woman's trust, so that the cops could catch the woman and the woman's criminal associates.
Can anyone identify this movie?

Should this question's header (Identifying a Movie called “Espionage”) be changed? It doesn't say anything about the movie, and it's misleading as the title is incorrect.

I think you are talking about the movie called "Entrapment", starring Sean Connery and  Catherine Zeta-Jones.
From Imdb: 

Following the theft of a highly-secured piece of artwork, an agent
  convinces her insurance agency employers to allow her to wriggle into
  the company of an aging but active master thief. Connery's burglar
  takes her on suspiciously and demands rigorous training before their
  first job together--stealing a highly-valued mask from a chichi party.
  Their deepening attraction and distrust could tear apart their
  partnership but the promise of a bigger prize (some eight billion odd
  dollars) by Zeta-Jones keeps the game interesting. Only, who's playing
  with whom?


Thanks!  That's the exactly the movie I'm thinking of.  I'm impressed that I got an answer so quickly.

@KeshavSrinivasan To this day the scene I remember most clearly is the laser security system navigation scene,

@TrishLing He trains her to do it with blindfolds on, right?

Oh, that's an easy one. Stick around and you'd be impressed beyond words by how helpful and knowledgeable this community can be.
